# Using Label Expression with multiple fields and assign different colors

Tags: qgis, python, labeling

I'm trying to use an expression to label a layer by using multiple fields, and assign different colors using QGIS 2.16.

In ArcGIS I am able to achieve this using the following expression:

```py
def FindLabel([DesceasedName], [ownerName], [all_spaceid]):  
  
  if [DesceasedName] = "":  
    return "<BOL><FNT size = '5'>" + [DesceasedName] + "</FNT></BOL>"+   '\n' + "<CLR red='115' green='38' blue='0'><BOL>" + [all_spaceid] + "</BOL></CLR>" 
  elif [DesceasedName] == "":  
    return "<CLR blue='255'><FNT size = '5'>" + [ownerName] + "</FNT></CLR>"  + '\n' + "<CLR red='115' green='38' blue='0'><BOL>" + [all_spaceid] + "</BOL></CLR>"
  else:  
    return ""
```

How to achieve the same labeling in QGIS?

Answer (score 4):

You could try rule based labeling:

[image]

Comment: Thank you i already tried that, did not work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by did not work

Comment: do you have a specific reason to use QGIS 2.16? Any chance to install a newer version? 3.10 or 3.14?

Comment: No specific reason, I can upgrade to LTR 3.10